# Playing a video with mediaplayercontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, mpmediaplayercontroller

I'm trying to make a player, that gets a url from a tableview (not done yet).
I started trying to make the player work, with MPMediaPlayerController.

```
NSString *video = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GurkREc-q4I"];

    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:video];

    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc]initWithContentURL:url];

    [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:[self.view frame]];

    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController];
    [moviePlayerController setShouldAutoplay:YES];
    [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay];
    moviePlayerController.fullscreen = YES;
    [moviePlayerController play];
```

When I try to add the moviePLayer as a subview I get this warning: Incompatible pointer types sending 'MPMoviePlayerController *' to parameter of type 'UIView *'.

Also, when I open the view, the app closes, and in console we have this:

> 2014-03-04 18:26:50.696 FavVideos[6181:70b] -[MPMoviePlayerController
>   superview]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0xa63c470
>   2014-03-04 18:26:50.735 FavVideos[6181:70b] *** Terminating app due to
>   uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason:
>   '-[MPMoviePlayerController superview]: unrecognized selector sent to
>   instance 0xa63c470'

Any ideas about what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks since now.

Edit:

Ok, I saw what I was doing to get the error and the "crash".

Here:

```
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController];
```

I changed to:

```
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

No more warnings or crashes.
But the player is just a black screen, any ideas?

Comment: I saw in some sites that when mediaplayer detects a youtube url, it tries to launch the app. Can I make something to play this video in my app with the mediaplayer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason it is blank is that the file will need to be a supported format. The list of suitable formats can be found in the Apple docs here [Suitable Formats](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MediaPlayer/Reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW20), i.e. MPEG, H.264 etc.

Currently you're asking the MPMoviePlayer to play a url, though this is the url to direct to a youtube page with a movie on it. The url will need to be the actual movie file.

Ways you can play this youtube video would be either to open the view up as a webview, directed to this youtube page, or read the [Google documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/) to play within the app using their api.

I hope this helps,

Cheers, Jim.

Comment: Oh, I see. Well, I'll try to use the google documentation to make it work. Thank you.